# JSON with CSV array to SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have the following JSON data structure, that I am getting from an API:

```
{"Data":"header1,header2,header3,header4\\n9datacolumn1,datacolumn2,datacolumn3,datacolumn4\\n9datacolumn1,datacolumn2,datacolumn3,datacolumn4"}
```

As you can see, this is pretty much a CSV, with the comma being the delimiter and "\n9" being the line feed / row delimiter.

I pass this json string to a stored procedure, and the stored procedure should insert the data in a table.

I am using SQL Server 2017 so I can use JSON queries. Could anyone help me with the query to insert the data into a SQL table?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

As Ordinal position is really important here, then I suggest against `STRING_SPLIT`, which has no idea what ordinal position is. As a result I use [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2), and ***assume*** the value of `@JSON` will never be over 8,000 characters (or 4,000 if you were to use `DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD`):

```
DECLARE @JSON varchar(8000) = '{"Data":"header1,header2,header3,header4\\n9datacolumn1,datacolumn2,datacolumn3,datacolumn4\\n9datacolumn1,datacolumn2,datacolumn3,datacolumn4"}';

SELECT MAX(CASE DSc.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DSc.Item END) AS Column1,
       MAX(CASE DSc.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN DSc.Item END) AS Column2,
       MAX(CASE DSc.ItemNumber WHEN 3 THEN DSc.Item END) AS Column3,
       MAX(CASE DSc.ItemNumber WHEN 4 THEN DSc.Item END) AS Column4--, --You get the idea now
       --MAX(CASE DSc.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DSc.Item END) AS Column5,
       --MAX(CASE DSc.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DSc.Item END) AS Column6
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) OJ
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(OJ.[value],'\n9','|')))V([value]) --If you do use a Pipe (|) in your data, use a different character
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.[value],'|') DSr
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(DSr.Item,',') DSc

--WHERE DSr.ItemNumber > 1 --Uncomment if you don't want the Header Row
GROUP BY DSr.ItemNumber
ORDER BY DSr.ItemNumber;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce90a46810f14e18ca39acf805a2717b)

Comment: that is amazing! Thank you Larnu. Is there any way to make the header1, header2 etc as the column names instead of column1, column2?

Comment: Not without Dynamic SQL @ImperialBert